# MyBatis hits Cannot Assign Requested Address Socket Exception at high volume with Pooled connection

Tags: java, linux, postgresql, mybatis

I am using MyBatis to pull data from database into a cache as needed.  At high volumes of message traffic, I start to see the following exception:

```
 ### Error querying database. Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to <my-database>:<my-port> refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is 
 accepting TCP/IP connections.
 ### The error may exist in mappers/<my-mapper>.xml
 ### The error may involve <my-mapper>.getById
 ### The error occurred while executing a query
 ### Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to <my-database>:<my-port> refused. Check that 
 the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:30)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:122)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:113)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectOne(DefaultSqlSession.java:73)

<truncated>

 Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to <my-database>:<my-port> refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:262)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:52)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:216)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:404)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:272)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at org.apache.ibatis.datasource.unpooled.UnpooledDataSource.doGetConnection(UnpooledDataSource.java:201)
    at org.apache.ibatis.datasource.unpooled.UnpooledDataSource.doGetConnection(UnpooledDataSource.java:196)
    at org.apache.ibatis.datasource.unpooled.UnpooledDataSource.getConnection(UnpooledDataSource.java:93)
    at org.apache.ibatis.datasource.pooled.PooledDataSource.popConnection(PooledDataSource.java:385)
    at org.apache.ibatis.datasource.pooled.PooledDataSource.getConnection(PooledDataSource.java:89)
    at org.apache.ibatis.transaction.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.openConnection(JdbcTransaction.java:140)
    at org.apache.ibatis.transaction.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.getConnection(JdbcTransaction.java:62)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.getConnection(BaseExecutor.java:315)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.prepareStatement(SimpleExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doQuery(SimpleExecutor.java:61)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:303)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:102)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:82)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:120)
    ... 16 more
 Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Cannot assign requested address (connect failed)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:61)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:144)
    ... 37 more
```

I do not see these exceptions with small amounts of traffic, only at scale, so it doesn't seem to be any sort of functional problem or syntax issue with the mapper.  In my config file for mybatis, this is how my source is configured:

```
<environments default = "ingestion_environment">
    <environment id = "ingestion_environment">
        <transactionManager type = "JDBC"/>

        <dataSource type = "POOLED">
            <property name = "driver" value = "org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://<my-database>:<my-port>/<my-user>" />
            <property name="username" value="<username>" />
            <property name="password" value="<password>" />
            <property name="poolMaximumCheckoutTime" value="50000"/>
            <property name="poolMaximumActiveConnections" value="10"/>
        </dataSource>
    </environment>
</environments>
```

I'm trying to figure out what about high traffic could lead to these exceptions--with a pooled connection, it seems like the number of connections really shouldn't be changing even when there are more messages to handle.  What could cause this?

Comment: The connection is refused at network level, not JDBC level. It could be some kind of packet filter or firewall. It could also be the server's network/socket settings.

Comment: So the problem is unlikely to be directly related to MyBatis or its configuration, then.  I'll take a look at the network side of things, but I'm still a little curious--if the MyBatis connection is really pooled, shouldn't the number of connections be (if not constant) at least bounded?

Comment: Are you saying that the `PooledDataSource` created more connections than the number specified in `poolMaximumActiveConnections`? If so, you should add that information to the question (the result of `PooledDataSource.getPoolState().getActiveConnectionCount()` will suffice). And, just to be sure, there is only one instance of `PooledDataSource`, is that correct?

Comment: There is only one instance of the PooledDataSource as far as I can tell--but it is being used in a multithreaded context and each time a new thread uses it they start up a new session.  Should I instead be using one session and passing it around to different threads?

I've run pg_top on the postgres server and confirmed that there are 100 processes on the database that are entirely from my application, and *should* only be from MyBatis.  I don't know if this is a full 1:1 mapping with MyBatis connections for sure, though.  I'll try to get some of this info from MyBatis directly.

Comment: As far as MyBatis and the "getActiveConnectionCount()" method is concerned, we never go above the configured number of connections--in this case 15.  The postgres server is supposedly configured to allow up to 250 connections.  When I run pg_top, it says we have something like 110 connections.  A whole lot of numbers not lining up.

Comment: Here is a [demo](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/master/so-61822181) that does what you described and it seems to be working as I expect (no connection leak). You should enable logging and see what is going on.